# Formula or upper bound for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 {n\choose i} a^i b^{n-i}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to upper bound (or find a closed form for):
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 {n\choose i} a^i b^{n-i} $$
This seems really close to the binomial formula $\sum_{i=1}^n {n\choose i} a^ib^{n-i} = (a+b)^n$, so I was wondering if there's an easy way to deal with sums of this type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(ax)^ib^{n-i}=(ax+b)^n$, you can apply $x\tfrac{d}{dx}$ three times, then set $x=1$. The $i=0$ lower limit has the same effect as taking $i=1$, because $0^3=0$.

Comment: Nice trick. Thanks